# Python Mock not asserting calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm using the mock library to patch a class in a program that connects to a external resource and sends  a dictioanry.

The structure goes a litle like this...

code.py

```
def make_connection():
    connection = OriginalClass(host, port)
    connection.connect()
    connection.send(param)
    connection.close()
```

test.py

```
@mock.path('code.OriginalClass')
def test_connection(self, mocked_conn):
    code.make_connection()
    mocked_conn.assert_called_with(host, port)
    mocked_conn.connect.assert_called_once()
    mocked_conn.send.assert_called_with(param)
```

The first assert_called_with works perfectly, but the calls to method of the mocked class
don't pass. I have tried using patch.object as a decorator also with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect()` and `send()` methods are called on the *return value* of the first call; adjust your test accordingly:

```
mocked_conn.return_value.connect.assert_called_once()
mocked_conn.return_value.send.assert_called_with(param)
```

I usually store a reference to the 'instance' first:

```
@mock.path('code.OriginalClass')
def test_connection(self, mocked_conn):
    code.make_connection()
    mocked_conn.assert_called_with(host, port)
    mocked_instance = mocked_conn.return_value
    mocked_instance.connect.assert_called_once()
    mocked_instance.send.assert_called_with(param)
```

Comment: Incredible, i can't believe i didn't see that. Can i upvote this over 9000? Thanks a huge steaming pile of lots. :D
I'm going to start keeping that reference from now on, avoiding headaches like this again.