# Python patch mock appears to be called, but assert fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm using Python 2.6.6

What I'm trying to do is replace the creation of an object with a Mock, to make sure that the correct calls are made. Should be straightforward.

My Module:

```
import dir.SubModule

class Cls( object ):
    def Start( self ):
        self.__obj = dir.SubModule.SubCls()
        self.__obj.foo()
```

My Test:

```
import MyModule
import unittest
from mock import Mock, MagicMock, patch

class MyTest( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self.uut = MyModule.Cls()

    def test_one( self ):
        with patch( 'dir.SubModule.SubCls', spec=True ) as mockObj:
            print "mock calls before"
            print mockObj.mock_calls
            self.uut.Start()

            print "called: "      + str( mockObj.called )
            print "foo called: " + str( mockObj.foo.called )
            print "call_count: "  + str( mockObj.call_count )
            print "call_args: "   + str( mockObj.call_args )
            print "args_list: "   + str( mockObj.call_args_list )
            print "mock calls:\n" + str( mockObj.mock_calls )
            print "method calls:\n " + str( mockObj.method_calls )
```

The output is:

```
mock calls before:
[]
called: True
foo called: False
call_count: 1
call_args: call()
args_list: [call()]
mock calls:
[call(), call().foo()]
method calls:
[]
```

Yet the test fails:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: foo()
Not called
```

I don't get how the mock can report that the calls were made, but I can't assert that they were called. What am I missing?

EDIT:
After adding in reporting of all the metrics, it seems there is something fundamental that I'm misunderstanding about python mocks. If foo() is in the calls list, then why is the call count only 1, and why does foo.called report 'False'?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't seem to match the code you actually ran well enough for us to help you. It looks like the code you've posted has an entirely different set of bugs.

Comment: The only bug I found was that I was missing the setUp() declaration in front of my uut object creation; otherwise it is the code I'm running, except that I've removed the other unnecessary object and variable creation and use (which I've proved because it is commented out in my code.)

Comment: I really wish you would have written something more practical. I'm struggling wrapping my head around `foo`s and improper Python casing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mockObj.foo` is never called in this test. `self.uut.Start()` calls `mockObj`, creating a new mock, and then calls *that mock's* `foo` method. If you want to assert that this call happened, you will need to access the correct object:

```
mockObj.return_value.foo.assert_called_with()
```

Comment: Ah! I read about something similar in another article. I need to find that and link it, it had a pretty good explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343600/python-mock-not-asserting-calls)

My simple fix:

```
with patch( 'class' ) as mockCreator:
    mockObj = mockCreator.return_value
```

Then I can use 'mockObj' willy-nilly.

I ran across the linked solution last week when I was first learning about mocks - a bit too soon for the information to quite sink in.

Answer (score 0):

Mock assert syntax has many quirks. To handle it I wrote a [helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to
generate the asserts for me.

Here is how you would use it for your test method:

```
import MyModule
import unittest
from mock import patch

class MyTest( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self.uut = MyModule.Cls()

    def test_one( self ):
        with patch( 'dir.SubModule.SubCls', spec=True ) as mockObj:
            self.uut.Start()

            # calls to generate_asserts, put this after the 'act'
            import mock_autogen.generator
            print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(mockObj))
```

The output you get is:

```
assert 1 == mockObj.call_count
mockObj.assert_called_once_with()
mockObj.return_value.foo.assert_called_once_with()
```

Which correlates to the `__init__` call, followed by the call to `foo` of the newly created object.

So no more need to figure out the exact syntax by yourself, just apply the tool :)